# "Cannot use import statement outside a module error" error when running unit tests

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, jestjs, ckeditor

I'm running into a `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error when trying to run my vue 2 / jest unit tests. I added this to my jest.config but still getting the error. Seems like the ckeditor is trying to import code internally that isn't getting caught by the jest transpiling.

```
import { Editor, DataApiMixin, ElementApiMixin, attachToForm } from 'ckeditor5/src/core';

transformIgnorePatterns: [ '\\\\/node_modules\\\\/(?!@ckeditor).+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|vue)$'],
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474661/using-ckeditor-with-angular-and-jest/67214872#67214872) and others similar to it to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue by using `require` instead of `import`.

Maybe you could try:

```js
// import { Editor, DataApiMixin, ElementApiMixin, attachToForm } from 'ckeditor5/src/core';
const { Editor, DataApiMixin, ElementApiMixin, attachToForm } = require('ckeditor5/src/core');
```

Comment: Were you actually using those imports anywhere? I'm not actually using these `Editor, DataApiMixin, ElementApiMixin, attachToForm` modules but seems like the CkEditor is using them internally but can't transpile them or something.

Comment: Guessing it's an issue with the regex used for `transformIgnorePatterns`